# How to insert html container < > characters

Tags: jquery

I need to dynamically add values to a select field via jquery. The values are email addresses, constructed like: `"Name" <email@email.com>`

My code looks like this (where the variable "email" is the value to be inserted):

```
$("select[name='field_name']").append("<option value='" + email + "'>" + email + "</option>");
```

When it's getting inserted, the value is inserted correctly because it's enclosed in single parens. But the label (between the option tags) has the email address stripped -- presumably because it's enclosed in < >. How can I work with that value safely?

Comment: You should never have these kinds of values in an option. Anyways you could try replacing "<" and ">" with "&lt;" and "&gt;"

Answer (score 3):

Generate `option` element [using jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/#creating-new-elements) and set [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text) property as the content.

```
$("select[name='field_name']").append($('<option/>',{
   value: email,
   text: email
}));
```